# Ajax updating progress real time of system operations

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I am writing a web based GUI interface for a large Python script used to plumb a few activities on a server. While the application itself is very light weight, I am using Django to create the web GUI, because I can reuse many of the already builtin features such as user management among other.

I have a function, that takes number of logical steps, checks, copying of files. In the vanilla program we were using a log file to capture all statuses. Customer wants a page which shows each step with status changes in real time.

What is the right strategy. What are the steps taken? A progess bar is not what I require, it's more a progress report in real time? Can you advise the steps to be taken or point to any tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to poll the backend from the browser periodically to see if there are any updates. This does assume that the long-running script is running asynchronously. The periodic update is akin to a log file tail, once in a while you check if new information has been added to the log.

There are several existing jQuery plugins that'll help you build this; [PeriodicalUpdater for jQuery](http://www.360innovate.co.uk/blog/2009/03/periodicalupdater-for-jquery/) is a nice one, in that it'll adjust the poll interval if the server response doesn't change in a while.

Basically, with such a plugin, you'll need a Django view that returns the current status, the log file output of your process so to speak, and have PeriodicalUpdater poll that view. In the callback function for PeriodicalUpdater you'll need to add a check that the process is complete, of course; perhaps your server view could end with an easy to detect "Process complete" line at the end of the "log", or return a response that *only* consists of the final status.

Comment: See the function typically does about 10 steps, like copy file, change permissions etc, and I want to capture whether this was done successfully. Entire process takes up to 3 minutes, I need an ajax plugin that will update each status, and then stop announcing that function is over. It's a kind of progress bar, but instead update each step and provide a green mark, if it's successful or something went wrong.

Comment: Then your progress view returns those steps pre-rendered with the checkmarks as the steps complete, the poll is still going to have to call it.